# Entity Framework Code First Entity Splitting without virtual navigation properties?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've been trying to solve this all afternoon but have come up empty. Our schema doesn't seem quite right, but I don't have the power to change it.

Essentially I need to combine these 3 tables:

```
dbo.Charity
    Id  (PK, int, not null)
    Name (varchar(100), not null)

dbo.CharityCountry
    CharityId (PK, FK, int, not null)
    CountryId (PK, FK, int, not null)

dbo.Country
    Id  (PK, int, not null)
    Name (varchar(100), not null)
```

And get them into an EF model:

But i am utterly confused because many of the articles seems to leave out how to do this with a Mapping class:

```
public class CharityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Charity>
{
    public CharityMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        this.ToTable("dbo.Charity");

        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        ...
    }
 }
```

What I need to know is what to put into the ..., I am not sure how to map a composited entity association where the foreign key is absent from the Primary entity.

The charity object looks like:

```
public class Charity
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

And the Country object:

```
public class Country
{      
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you a safari books online account
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449317867 this book from Julie Lerman is very Useful.

Here is a free article for Julie on Doing Foreign Keys without navigational properties as in your example.  It is possible but its harder to work with.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532098.aspx?sdmr=JulieLerman&sdmi=authors
See the column Making Do with Absent Foreign Keys